# Calculate a percent with SCSS/SASS

Tags: css, sass

I want to set a width in percentage in scss via calculation, but it gives me errors..

> Invalid CSS after "...-width: (4/12)%": expected expression (e.g. 1px,
>   bold), was ";"

I want to do something like

```
$my_width: (4/12)%;

div{
width: $my_width;
}
```

how do I add the % sign in there?

Same question with px and em

Comment: There is nothing to fiddle. I just want to add the unit of the number to the calculation. Same as (400/20)px. How do I have a number and px/em/% in scss? That way I could have "global variables" I can change once

Comment: Try to add a bracket like $my_width: ((4/12)%);

Comment: Oops.. Sorry, I didn't have a chance to check it and give a one more try to do this.. {$my_width: (4/12)%;}

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Have you tried the [percentage](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#percentage-instance_method) function ?

```scss
$my_width: percentage(4/12);
div{
    width: $my_width;
}
```

---

##### UPDATE

This function was updated since version 1.33.0 and now this is a correct method to do it:

```scss
@use "sass:math";

div {
    width: math.percentage(math.div(4,12));
}
```

Source: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#percentage

Comment: is there a similar function for px and em?

Comment: Not sure, but in the source section of the documentation you can see the underlying logic: Sass::Script::Number.new(value.value * 100, ['%']), so I would think that if they do not exist you could do this directly, or create some wrapper functions yourself.

Comment: @NickGinanto for px you can just add `+px` to the end of the line, e.g. `width: ($foo + $bar) +px`

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat No, you should **never** do that ever under any circumstance.  Adding units should be done via multiplication (eg. `$foo + $bar * 1px`), concatenating the unit on like that only gives you a string.

Comment: @cimmanon did that change recently? I'm sure it wasn't the case when I posted my comment.

Comment: As far as I am aware, it was never the case.

Answer (score 34):

Another way:

```
$my_width: 4/12 * 100%;

div {
    width: $my_width; // 33.33333%
}
```

Sass will output the value in %.

Comment: Note that I had to use 100 / 6 * 1% to make this work for me, or else I ended up with 1666.67%.

Comment: where can I find a documentation what * 100% actually does?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to make it work this way:

```
div{
   width: (4/12)* 1%;
   }
```

This way you don't need to use any special function.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna use a loop, maybe this solution will be working

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i} {
        width: #{calc(100 * $i / 12) + '%'};
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I have tried because i wanted to "s" after calculating